# How we can make a AJAX like functionality from email template

Tags: php, yii2

I need a button in my email, on clicking the button i need to change a status in my Db with out redirecting. Is it possible? Or is there any Free API or third party tool for doing this in PHP

Comment: I don't think it is possible without actually redirecting to the link.

Comment: Is there any API available?

Comment: Since it is not possible because of security reasons so no chance of any API existence.

Comment: i have seen some emails with this functionality.... then how they are doing this? any idea?

Comment: you want to update in your database the status for the email as `"Read"` when the button is clicked?

Comment: ok can i get a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed Javascript in emails.

You can try with an iframe that can use ajax or whatever else you prefer, **BUT** your email will be seen as spam from the most of providers, or won't work on many applications.

Here is a sort of compatibility list: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/01/do-iframes-work-in-email/

You can search or ask for less invasive solutions.